# Regex issue in R with gsub - reformat string vector to numeric

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to take a character vector of dollar values that is poorly formatted and turn it into a numeric.  The values are formatted as in the following vector, with a leading and trailing space, a comma, and a dollar sign:

```
x <- c(" 18,000.50 ", " $1,240.30 ", " $125.00 ")
```

I am trying to use the following function to get rid of all characters other than the digits and the dot, but it isn't working:

```
trim_currency <- function(x) grep("\$([0-9.]*)\,([0-9.]*)", x, values=TRUE)
```

I got the regex code

```
\$([0-9.]*)\,([0-9.]*)
```

to run successfully with this regex tester
http://regex101.com/r/qM2uG0

When I run it in R, I get the following error:

```
Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\$"
```

Any ideas about how I can do this in R?

---

Thanks to ***ndoogan*** for his response.  That solves this particular issue.  However, if I wanted to make it more general, I would ask:

How could I use R/regex to run a vector through a filter, allowing only the digits and periods to come through?

Comment: R subscribes to the "more cowbell" theory of regex. Needs more backslashes.

Comment: i'm realizing now that grep is the wrong function to use....  The regex is working thanks to joran, but now i need to actually use the regex as a filter rather than just select observations that match.

Comment: Probably you want `gsub`, which is conveniently described on the same manual page that you must have looked at for `?grep`, and is contained in your title, now that I think about it.

Comment: yeah is there a way for me to use gsub like:

    gsub(".*","\\$([0-9.]*)\\,([0-9.]*)", x)

Comment: im going to edit my question, one sec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x <- c(" 18,000.50 ", " $1,240.30 ", " $125.00 ")
gsub("[,$ ]","",x)
#[1] "18000.50" "1240.30"  "125.00"
```

Add more characters within the brackets to eliminate different things. I assume the example `x` is exhaustive here.

**Update**

If you know you're only interested in numeric digits and decimal points, then you could do this:

```
gsub("[^0-9.]","",x)
#[1] "18000.50" "1240.30"  "125.00"
```

The `^` inside the square brackets *negates* the meaning of the statement in square brackets.

Finally, to get resulting values into numeric form, wrap the `gsub()` function (or an object containing its output) in `as.numeric()`:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]","",x))
#[1] 18000.5  1240.3   125.0
```

Comment: perfect, i got so caught up in the regex tester i lost track of how R actually interprets it.  all you have to do is find the characters you don't want.

Comment: So, what if the data if the data cleanliness issues were a little less consistent and I had to apply a filter that only allowed numbers and periods.  How could I do this in R?

Comment: +1 - and I assume you'll want to pass the output through `as.numeric`.